# How can I get the alpha value of a CGContext?

Tags: core-graphics, cgcontext

Core Graphics defines [setAlpha](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456404-setalpha) on CGContext, but no getAlpha. Is there any way to get a CGContext's alpha value?

Comment: `CGContext` has many `setXXX` methods with no corresponding way to get the value later. I never really noticed that before.